# Is there a workaround for the Chateau grenade glitch?

Tags: uncharted-3

I can't move forwards in the Chateau as it freezes when I get to the grenade tutorial. No matter how long or short I hold L2 for it will not throw a grenade. All other function via the start button are fine i.e. option, bonus etc. but it won't throw a **bleep** grenade. Can somebody please tell me how to proceed.

Comment: I've just had exactly the same thing happen in exactly the same place! D'oh!

Comment: Same here guys, restarted the level and got stuck in the same spot

Comment: It's late 2014 and I just stumbled upon this "glitch".. here's what worked for me: http://community.us.playstation.com/t5/UNCHARTED-3-Drake-s-Deception/logic-freeze-at-the-Chateau-grenade-grab/m-p/44684908#M6399

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I fixed it by restarting my singleplayer game and now it works fine for me but there is just a little lag when I tro granades.

1. if you have tryed that then it you will need to return the game and get a new one.
2. it just might be your ps3 problem.
3. or you can try changing the controls so you throw your grenade and you can change it back later with a different button 
   for example "changing the L2 to R2

Answer (score 0):

I set the PS up to the Playstation network(hadnt got round to it b4) and put the network pass in from the back of the booklet that comes with the game, it now works

Answer (score -3):

You are probably pressing R2 and not L2!  Many people were having the same issue.  L2 is under L1.  I was having this issue until I realized I was pressing the wrong button.